# add linke to UIVewiTabelCell with Disclosure Indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add link to custom cell when user click Disclosure Indicator ,app go to other view depend on cell content 
how i Know the content of cell if it selected by user

Comment: Check out the function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. You can then gather the information about that row with the `[indexPath.row]`. In my case I have an array of data in my table. I can access it like this: `myData[indexPath.row].someProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustemTableViewCell {
    // here you can access the cell and it's content
  }
}
```

Comment: the content of custom cell never show after i do this inside the function                                 
  cell.myText

Comment: what is the class name of your custom cell?